# Trying to write a script to push a box using mouse pointer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm in the beginning of learning JavaScript, and trying to write a script that allows the user to push a box left and right using mouse pointer.

I managed to work it out when the pointer touches the left side of the box, but I'm facing two problems here:

1. When the pointer gets inside the box, the box jumps to the new coordinate. I want the box to stay in it's position when the pointer gets inside the box.
2. I really can't figure it out when the mouse touches the right side of the box. I want the box to get pushed left. I've made a `box.offsetRight` property to help me out but just can't use it efficiently.

Here's a picture to demonstrate what I mean:

[image]

The "X" mark is where the pointer is. And heading toward the right side of the box. How to push the box to the left ?

Here's what i've tried to do (it didn't work of course) :

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Chase the box</title>
        <style>
            body {
            }

            .css-box{
                position: absolute ;
                top:20px;
                width : 100px;
                height : 100px;
                background-color : blue;
            }

            .css-textbox{
                margin-top: 500px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="box" class="css-box"></div>
        <div class="css-textbox">            
            <p>All : <input id="allTextbox" type="text"></input></p>
            <p>Left : <input id="leftTextbox" type="text"></input></p>
            <p>Right : <input id="rightTextbox" type="text"></input></p>
            <p>e.pageX(Left) : <input id="pageXTextbox" type="text"></input></p>
            <p>e.pageX(Right) : <input id="pageXRightTextbox" type="text"></input></p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="helper.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var allTextbox = document.getElementById("allTextbox");
var leftTextbox = document.getElementById("leftTextbox");
var rightTextbox = document.getElementById("rightTextbox");
var pageXTextbox = document.getElementById("pageXTextbox");
var PageXRightTextbox = document.getElementById("pageXRightTextbox");

Object.prototype.offsetRight = window.innerWidth - (box.offsetWidth + box.offsetLeft);

var pushBox = function(e){
    
    var pageXRight = window.innerWidth - e.pageX;
    box.offsetRight = window.innerWidth - (box.offsetWidth + box.offsetLeft);

    if (e.pageX >= box.offsetLeft){
        box.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
    } else if(pageXRight >= box.offsetRight){
        box.style.right = pageXRight  + "px";
    }

    allTextbox.value = window.innerWidth;
    leftTextbox.value = box.offsetLeft;
    rightTextbox.value = box.offsetRight;
    pageXTextbox.value = e.pageX;
    pageXRightTextbox.value = pageXRight;

};

box.addEventListener("mousemove" , pushBox);
```

I hope to find an answer using JavaScript not jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible idea for you. Sounds like some carousels I've coded up in AS3.

1. When mouse over the div container for the box you start checking mouse position on a timer (fairly fast).
2. using mouse X, div width, box width you can calculate if the mouse is on the left or the right of the box. You probably want ranged hit area on both sides of the box so that it moves when mouse hits that to new position. (I assume your box is position relative css inside its container which will allow css:left and css:right to be animated via document.getElementById("xxx").style
3. Careful when box gets to left and right side limits as you still want a hit area.

I would suggest creating a few text boxes for number outputs so you can see how numbers change when your timer function is checking mouse positions etc and then you should be able to make the calculations.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've made a lot of changes and hope if you can help me in the new question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11603411/whats-wrong-with-this-javascript-script